# No sound in shadow-grounds survivor ? (64bit)

Tags: 11.04, sound, games

I start the game and there is no sound.
What shoudl I do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing you have 64 bit Ubuntu installed. If so, open a terminal and type:

```
cd Installfolderlocation/survivor/lib32/
```

obviously replace "Installfolderlocation" with the path you chose to install the game to.

```
mv libasound.so.2 libasound.so.2_old
ln -s /usr/lib32/libasound.so.2 libasound.so.2
```

These commands will rename a sound library shipped with the Game, and replace it with a symlink to the corresponding library shipped with Ubuntu.

Sound should work afterwards. (Tested on Ubuntu 11.04 64bit.)

Comment: yes I have ubuntu 64-bit.

Comment: well did it work then?

Comment: It worked well after rebooting the system. Thanks!

Comment: np, glad to hear it!

Answer (score 1):

Installing package 'libopenal1' fixed my problem. Now I have sound in Oilrush running on Ubuntu 11.10 64-bits.

```
sudo aptitude install libopenal1
```