# No sound in Oil Rush

Tags: sound, 64-bit, games

I've installed oil rush using desura (currently in beta) using ubuntu 11.04 64 bit. The game runs perfectly fine except I can't hear any sound. What suggestions do you have?

Note: I also had the same problem with shadowgrounds survivor and this fix [No sound in shadow-grounds survivor ? (64bit)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34855/no-sound-in-shadow-grounds-survivor-64bit?q=oil+rush+no+sound) worked for me. Problem is that oil-rush doesn't have a lib32/lib directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The folder you want to do that in is bin. The next build of Desura will fix libs to use your system libs over the ones packaged with the game so this issue doesnt happen.

Comment: Next version did indeed fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Installing the package `libopenal1` should fix the problem.